# Position a Pie Chart inside a Highcharts Stockchart Tooltip

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to position a semi circle donut chart inside tooltip of a time series area chart as in the below JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/bru187cj/74/

```
    tooltip: {
        shape:'circle',
        useHTML: true,
        formatter: function() {
            setTimeout( function() { 
                $("#tca").highcharts({
                    chart: {
                          height:200,
                        backgroundColor:null,
                        plotBackgroundColor: null,
                        plotBorderWidth: null,
                        plotShadow: false
                       },
                        title:{
                            text:''
                        },
                        credits:{
                            enabled:false
                        },
                        exporting: {
                            enabled: false
                        },   
                        plotOptions: {
                                pie: {
                                    dataLabels: {
                                        distance: 5
                                    }
                                }
                        },                        
                    series: [{
                        type:'pie',
        startAngle: -90,
        endAngle: 90,
        center: ['50%', '75%'],                            
                        innerSize:'60%',                            
                        data: [["A",15],["B",20],["C",3],["D",2]]
                    }]
                });
            }, 10)                      
            return "<div id='hc-tooltip'><div id='tca'></div></div>";
        }
    }
```

However as you an see from the result, the donut chart is showing up outside the tooltip area.  Note that this behaviour seems specific to StockChart.

Hope someone can help here.

Comment: It is the `center: ['50%', '75%'], ` part of your config that makes it appear outside of the box.Using `center: ['15%', '-5%'], and size: '20%'` gives you the plot in the tooltipbox. See example: https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/bru187cj/145/

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Though technically it now sits inside the tooltip, I was hoping to find a solution where the hight of the tooltip adjusts to the height of the semi circle donut chart (200) so that the donut sits in the middle of the div with height of 200.

Comment: For that I think you will have to override the default tooltip creating function. However, an easy workaround, that looks alright, is to increase the fontsize of the tooltip. Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/bru187cj/174/

Answer (score 0):

You can set **height** style for the chart container in tooltip, but it can not be higher than the main chart plot area height.

```
#hc-tooltip {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Eventaully, you can customize 'renderSplit' method in Tooltip prototype.

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/q7vm0w1z/